# How granular do questions need to be.  Can I ask a question that has 5 pieces?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to know which "known facts" have been investigated at all and [listed 5](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5118/which-if-any-of-these-beliefs-are-backed-up-by-any-statistics) inviting others to, in fact, add to the list.  Should I instead ask a separate question for each one?

Comment: I've broken them up into a bunch of separate questions (and am getting more answers that way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, these should all be separate questions.

Each question should address one specific topic. While some of the topics covered in your question are related, they are all specific enough to stand alone.

Also, as indicated in the comments, some of those questions have already been asked.

Comment: perhaps a tag: "old-wives-tales" could be used for grouping together questions that address proving/dispelling these with data?

Comment: @cabbey That's a really great idea!